# Change active control when user presses ENTER

Tags: vb.net

i am making my final year project in vb.net for data entry
i want to make the project more user friendly
i use code to change the control focus by pressing 'Enter'(ASCII 13)..
and clear the content of current control by pressing 'Esc'(ASCII 27)...
in my project one form contains at-least 300 of controls say(t1,t2,t3,t4...)

so in the keypress event of t1 i have writen

```
if asc(e.keychar)=13 then
     t2.focus
elseif asc(e.keychar)=27 then
     t1.text=nothing
end if
```

the code works fine but produce an alert beep when i press ENTER 
to change the active control...
please help me to remove the beep alert..

and because of 100 of controls it take lo

Answer (score 1):

KeyPressEventArgs.Handled=true;

so most probably

```
e.Handled=true;
```

also consider doing `e.KeyCode = Keys.Return` instead of `asc(e.keychar)`

Comment: if i am not wrong e.handled=true is use to deactivate the current key press event so it will not work in my problem..

Comment: but you handled it `t2.focus` here, no ?

Comment: e.KeyCode is in the keydown event not is the keypress event ok this may be my soln i will try it.. thanks man..

Comment: hi friend i tried e.keycode=keys.Enter but it is also producing the beep sound plz help????

Comment: and what about e.Handled=true; ? sry i dont have time now, gonna be late for classes again :P sum1 else will help you

Comment: `e.Handled=true` does not work. `e.SuppressKeyPress = True`  does.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think advancing to the next control when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> is a good idea.

These are some points to note from Microsoft's User Experience Guidelines:

> - **Tab key and tab stops.** The Tab key is the primary mechanism for navigating within a window. The Tab key visits only those controls with a tab stop. All interactive controls should have tab stops (unless they are in a group), whereas non-interactive controls, such as labels, should not.
> - **Tab order.** All controls with tab stops are visited in tab order. Pressing Tab moves input focus to the next control in tab order, whereas pressing Shift+Tab moves input focus to the previous control.
> - **Spacebar, Enter, and Esc keys.** The spacebar activates the control with input focus, whereas the Enter key activates the default button. Pressing the Esc key cancels or closes the window.

Anyone who is not new to computers can be expected to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get to the next control and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select the default button or the currently selected button.

Using the Enter key to navigate the controls on the form makes your project a non-starter for many people.

I recommend you set the tab order on your application in the way you'd like the user to navigate the controls and stop handling the enter key.

See the [Keyboard Section of the Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545460.aspx) for generally accepted rules on keyboard inputs.

Comment: ok thanks for your idea friend.. but i dont want to engage both hands during data entry... since the user will select most of the data from combo-box... once again thanks...

Comment: one more question?? becoz of 100s of control during form load the content of the form(means control) flickers... any idea to reduce this...

Comment: double buffering ? anyway you should ask that in a seperate question :P

Comment: If you have too many controls on your form you will definitely have flickering problems due to the way Winforms renders windows. It also means that your form is not well designed. You should consider using a [Tab Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx "TabControlClass - MSDN") to group/organise the controls on your form based on their purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem and I solve it with use "e.SuppressKeyPress = True" command...

```
if asc(e.keychar)=13 then
e.SuppressKeyPress = True 'Use this command where you don't want that sounds
     t2.focus
elseif asc(e.keychar)=27 then
     t1.text=nothing
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all the partial answers together and you get this:

```
If e.KeyData = Keys.Return Then
    SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, True, False, False, True)
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
ElseIf e.KeyData = Keys.Escape Then
    ActiveControl.Text = String.Empty
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
End If
```

This will always move to the next element and swallow the keypress, which avoids that sound you were hearing.

Notice that my code also doesn't contain any hardcoded element names. You can drop this in to the event handler for any text box and it will work with no modification.